# Replacing Boost MPL containers with C++17 features

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++17, boost-mpl

I have some old code based on MPL containers, using `enable_if` to to activate some dispatch like this:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<std::int16_t, std::int32_t, int64_t, float, double, std::complex<float>, std::complex<double> > Types;

template <typename Vector>
typename boost::enable_if<typename boost::mpl::empty<Vector>::type, void>::type void process(/*args*/)
{
}

template <typename Vector>
typename boost::disable_if<typename boost::mpl::empty<Vector>::type, void>::type void process(/*args*/)
{
    process<typename boost::mpl::pop_front<Vector>::type>();
}

void outside()
{
    process<Types>();
}
```

So with C++17, I can use constexpr, but I still that list of types that I have to pass in `outside`. Is there a proper way of declaring the container type so that I can use variadic templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest transition would be to swap Boost.MPL for [Boost.MP11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html):

```
using Types = mp_list<...>;


template <typename L>
void process() {
    if constexpr (!mp_empty<L>) {
        process<mp_pop_front<L>>();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that's probably what I need, thanks a lot, didn't see this new library.